# Spring Boot JPA Query with Multiple column Condition and IN clause with combination of two columns

Tags: java, spring, oracle, jpa, boot

I have a Employee class  and DB Table- Employee(Empid,Empname,EmpSalary,EmpJoiningDate)

Another class EmpData(Empid,EmpJoiningDate)
I have list ,  `List<EmpData> empdata = new ArrayList();`
Need to fetch all records from employee table with this combination using the empdata  list,
This query I need to run for all combinations from List using JPA

For single combination below query works fine.

```
@query(value="select * from employee where empid=:empid and empJoiningDate=:empJoiningDate")
List<Employee> fetchEmpData(@param("empid") String empid,@param("empJoiningDate") String empJoiningDate)
```

instead of firing a separate query for each (empid, empJoiningDate ) combination, i need to fire a single query for all (empid, empJoiningDate ) combinations present in list . Is there any way to do this ?

Help me to revise the above query to run on the list.

Comment: You can do it with SQL nut sure if JPQL supports it. In SQL you can use a tuple in the in clause something like `SELECT * FROM employee WHERE (empid, empJoiningDate) in ( (id1, date1), (id2, date2), ...)`. However this only works on certain databases (I think Oracle is one of those) but isn't supported in JPQL I believe.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, I will try as we are using Oracle

Answer (score 0):

If I assume Empid as primary key then why are you going for query. You already have your result set in your parameters.
So Your question is unclear. Relations are not defined.

I assume that you need to only two fields from DB to map into your EmpData Class and Empid and EmpJoiningDate has ManyToMany relation.

then use

```
    @query(value="select Empid, EmpJoiningDate from employee where empid=:empid 
    and empJoiningDate=:empJoiningDate", nativeQuery = true)
    List<EmpData> fetchEmpData(@param("empid") String 
     empid,@param("empJoiningDate") String empJoiningDate)
```

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: This is just an example similar to my use case. Consider empid and empJoiningDate are having 1:1 relation

Comment: Think like instead of firing a  separate query for (empid, empJoiningDate ) combination, i need to fire a single query for all combinations present in list . Is there any way to do this ?

Comment: @JMN If empId is primary key with1:1 relation then you can pass List of empId to get your result set in List.  @query(value="select * from employee where empid IN = :empids", nativeQuery = true)
List<Employee> fetchEmpData(@param("empid") List<String> empIds);      make sure you prepare List of empId from EmpData List and pass it to fetchEmpData function.

Comment: Consider empId  is not primary key and I need to check empid=:empid  and empJoiningDate=:empJoiningDate  in the query for each (empid, empJoiningDate ) pair

Comment: This code wouldn't even run as you cannot assign a list of parameters with `=` not to mention that this query would do something totally different as the user requested.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).